# Calling module controller function from page formulary in CodeIgniter 4.1 HMVC

Tags: forms, module, controller, codeigniter-4, hmvc

I'm working in an application HMVC CodeIgniter 4.1, all the routes work fine in navigator:

Navigator adress: **http://localhost/myapp/public/index.php/installation/shop-data**

My module Routes file contains:

```
$routes->group("installation", ["namespace" => "\Modules\Installation\Controllers"], function ($routes) {

    //Example URL: /installation/shop-data
    $routes->get("shop-data", "InstallationController::shop_data");
    $routes->get("shop-data-post", "InstallationController::shop_data_post");

});
```

**shop_data_post** is the function in which I insert the data to the database from the page Form using this:

```
echo form_open("installation/shop-data-post");
```

But I obtain this 404 error:

**Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Installation::shop-data-post**

How can I get my function correctly from my page formulary?

Thanks

Comment: From my understanding, CI4 expects the Controller to be within the app folder. So if you have another module, a better structure will be ROOTFOLDER -> MODULE_NAME -> app -> Controllers and the path should be included in the Autoload file.

Comment: Usually yes, but I'm working with HMVC format. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok finally I have solved this..

All that I must did was change my module Installation Routes file so:

This line:

```
$routes->get("shop-data-post", "InstallationController::shop_data_post");
```

For this:

```
$routes->match(["get", "post"], "shop-data-post", "InstallationController::shop_data_post");
```

The error was on the route request method. It must be POST for process the Form data